# Giving a specific size to the graph

Tags: gnuplot

For a specifically defined **figure size**, plotting a graph with and without axis options (labels, tics labels etc.) results in different **graph area size**.

Is there a way to set the **figure size** and the **graph area size** to get the same results with or without plotting the axis options ?

Of course I tried `set size square x,y` but this scales the graph area and not the axis options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I understand that you have a certain canvas or screen size, set e.g. by

```
set term wxt size 800,400
```

The margins (i.e. the space between graph border and screen border) are set automatically by default. If you want to have fixed margins use `set lmargin`, `set rmargin`, `set bmargin` and `set tmargin` or `set margins`. Check `help margins`.

**Code:**

```
### set margins
reset session

set xlabel "x-axis"
set ylabel "y-axis"

plot x**4

pause -1

set margins screen 0.2, screen 0.8, screen 0.2, screen 0.8    # l,r,b,t
replot

pause -1

unset tics
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
replot
### end of code
```

**Results:**  (All graphs have the same canvas size (here: 597x441 pixels). And graph 2 and 3 have a fixed margin, i.e. the same graph size with and without axes labels and tics.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice solution. That may sounds weird but I hadn't imagined to use margin to set le graph size. Thanks again !